# How to jump to the end of a word in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-navigation

I like the behavior of [Jumpy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wmaurer.vscode-jumpy), but it only supports jump to the start of a word, is there any way to jump to the end of a word in VSCode?

Demo of jumping to the start of a word in Jumpy:

[image]

Comment: Hi, original author of Jumpy for Atom here.  I've ported Jumpy to VS Code ("Jumpy2") https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidLGoldberg.jumpy2

I use vim's 'e' command to go the end of the word.  I agree with the below threads that Non vim users usually just use ctrl + (right arrow).  I like the looks of your feature though, can you switch it while the normal front of the word jump is enabled?

Comment: @David Yes, there're four different modes, you can switch to another mode while one mode is enabled. I agree this feature might not be very important for vim/neovim users, but I think it's quite convenient without doing the extra `e`/`ctrl + right arrow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Jump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.jump) extension, it supports:

- *Jump* to the *start* of a word
- *Jump* to the *end* of a word
- *Select* to the *start* of a word
- *Select* to the *end* of a word

Demo of jumping to the end of a word:

[image: Jump to the End of a word]